# Cannot update specific versions with maven versions plugin

Tags: maven, versioning, nexus

I have 3 artifacts, ArtifactA, ArtifactB and ArtifactC in a Nexus repository. Unfortunately, they don't share the same versioning.

ArtifactA has the following versions:

- 73.0.0.0-10
- 73.0.0.0-9
- 80.0.12.0-1

ArtifactB has the following versions:

- 7.3_0.0.0-10.noarch
- 7.3_0.0.0-9.noarch
- 8.0_0.12.0-1.noarch

ArtifactC has the following versions:

- 8.1_0.20.0-354
- 8.1_0.20.0-355
- 9.0_0.0.0-328

All Artifacts are dependencies in my bom file.

I want to use the versions-maven-plugin to check for updates and replace the versions in the bom where applicable. HOWEVER:

- For ArtifactA, i want to keep taking the latest versions starting with 73.0.*
- For ArtifactB, i want to keep taking the latest versions starting with 7.3_*
- For ArtifactC, i want to keep taking the latest versions starting with 8.1_*

My bom file for these specific artifacts looks like:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>xxx</groupId>
   <artifactId>ArtifactA</artifactId>
   <type>zip</type>
   <version>73.0.0.0-9</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>ArtifactB</artifactId>
    <type>rpm</type>
    <version>7.3_0.0.0-9.noarch</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>ArtifactC</artifactId>
    <type>rpm</type>
    <version>8.1_0.20.0-354</version>
 </dependency>
```

My first attempt goes with:

**mvn versions:use-latest-versions -f *bom_file***

The result is:

[INFO] Updated xxx:ArtifactA:zip:73.0.0.0-9 to version 80.0.12.0-1
[INFO] Updated xxx:ArtifactB:rpm:7.3_0.0.0-10.noarch to version 8.0_0.12.0-1.noarch
[INFO] Updated xxx:ArtifactC:rpm:8.1_0.20.0-354 to version 9.0_0.0.0-328

But this does not meet my requirements. For that reason, i chose to use the ***-DallowMajorUpdates=false*** flag. Now the result is the following:

[INFO] Updated xxx:ArtifactA:zip:73.0.0.0-9 to version 73.0.0.0-10

and that's it!!

Why can't the other 2 Artifact versions be updated? Is it because of the underscore within the version, so everything after the underscore is compared as string? If i cannot change the underscore (these rpms are not built by me), is there an alternative solution? What about the ***rulesUri*** option of the mojo? Could this be used in any way to help me?

Thank you all for your time!